# How to update the arrays of childforms with timer in c# winform?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, timer, auto-update

1. The array in the parent form is updated every 100 milliseconds.
2. Once the child form is opened with menustrip in parent form, the data is passed to child form

**Issue:**

1. Till now, I have had success in passing the array data, but I need to update it periodically in the `child` form also, and I have some difficulties with setting the timer in child form.
2. 

**Form1:** or Parent Form

```
string[] ArrayPack1Cells = new string[28];

//All the values are first stored in 2D array `volt_info_array[packidindex, voltage_index]` 
//and after scaling it, elements store in 1D array depending on the `packidindex` value
Voltages = ((volt_info_array[packidindex, voltage_index] / 1000));

switch(PackIndexes)
 {
   case 1:
        // if size is 28, then convert to array to be passed to child form.
       if(ListPack1Cells.Count == 28)
       {
           ArrayPack1Cells = ListPack1Cells.ToArray();
       }
       break;
   case 2:
   .....
 }
```

```
private void viewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ToolStripMenuItem menu = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
            
   switch (menu.Name)
   {
      case "pack1ToolStripMenuItem":
      if (Application.OpenForms["Pack1"] is Pack1 pack1)
       {
          pack1.Focus();
          return;
       }
       pack1 = new Pack1();
       pack1.TakeThis(ArrayPack1Cells);
       pack1.MdiParent = this;
       pack1.Show();
       Array.Clear(ArrayPack1Cells, 0, ArrayPack1Cells.Length);// Clear it once send to form2
       break;
}
```

**Form2:** or Child/Pack1 Form
[image]

`public void TakeThis(string[] ArrayPack1Cells)`,  method copies all the 28 arrays in the texboxes but only once.

```
public List<Control> Cell_Volt1 = new List<Control>();
public string[] f_temp = new string[28];

public Pack1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Cell_tbxArray();
  if (P1_timer.Enabled == false)
  {
    P1_timer.Enabled = true;
    P1_timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.P1_timer_Tick);
    P1_timer.Start();
  }
  else if (P1_timer.Enabled)
  {
    1_timer.Stop();
    P1_timer.Enabled = true;
    P1_timer.Start();
  }
}
private void Cell_tbxArray()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count; i++)
  {
    if (tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i].GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
      Cell_Volt1.Add(tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i]);
    }
  }
}

public void TakeThis(string[] ArrayPack1Cells)
{
  f_temp = ArrayPack1Cells;
  int index = 0;
  foreach (string item in f_temp)
  {
    Cell_Volt1[index].Text += item;
    index++;
  }
}
private void P1_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Cell_Volt1.Count; i++)
  {
    Cell_Volt1[i].Text += f_temp[i];
  }
}
```

The `private void P1_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)` isnt working at all.

Comment: I am sorry. The only way I see is to rewrite the whole thing from the scratch. But I can't be bothered. You are in the dark in so many places.. Perhaps someone more patient will come along and help. There are more responses on Monday normally ..

Comment: @BoppityBop okay sure, any way Thank you for going through this

Comment: I would move the responsability to update the second form in the first one. The one that receives the updates. So the Timer should be on the first form and at the interval you want send the new data to the second form. You already have a TakeThis method that updates the textboxes on the second form. You can call it again from the first form when the timer ticks.

Comment: @Steve - the general idea is correct. it is normally used when rate of the **data updates** is too high (eg too much computing power will be used to keep UI in sync or it is too fast for user to see or there is no business requirement to keep it in sync. so one thread updates data as fast as it can and the other thread refreshes the UI as fast is it need. OP is already confused. dont help him to get more confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my take.

Parent:

```
public static class Consts
{
    public const int NPACKS = 10, NVOLTS = 28;
}

public partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    double[,] data = new double[Consts.NPACKS, Consts.NVOLTS];
    double[][] uidata = new double[Consts.NPACKS][];
    Dictionary<int, PackForm> forms = new Dictionary<int, PackForm>();

    public ParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < Consts.NPACKS; i++)
        {
            uidata[i] = new double[Consts.NVOLTS];
        }
    }

    // wild guess - not clear how do you update it - all of them or slices
    void DataContinuousUpdate(double value, int npack, int nvolt)
    {
        data[npack, nvolt] = value;

        var slice = uidata[npack];

        // in case a form is trying to refresh UI
        lock (slice)
            slice[nvolt] = value;
    }

    void OpenPack(int npack)
    {
        // assuming access to this method is serial
        if (forms.ContainsKey(npack))
            return;

        var slice = uidata[npack];

        lock (slice)
        {
            var form = new PackForm(npack, slice);
            forms.Add(npack, form);
        }
    }
}
```

Pack:

```
public partial class PackForm : Form
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public double[] Data { get; private set; }
    public double ValueScale { get; set; }

    TextBox[] VoltTextBox = new TextBox[Consts.NVOLTS];
        
    Timer timer;

    private PackForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CreateTextBoxes();

        ValueScale = 1000.0;

        this.FormClosing += PackForm_FormClosing;
    }
        

    public PackForm(int iD, double[] data) : this()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ID = iD;
        Data = data;

        StartTimer();
    }

    private void PackForm_FormClosing(object? sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        StopTimer();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void StartTimer()
    {
        StopTimer();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        if (timer == null) return;

        timer.Enabled = false;
        timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick;
    }
    private void Timer_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Data == null) return;

        lock(Data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Data.Length; i++)
            {
                VoltTextBox[i].Text += Data[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you So much, I really appreciate your kind help